# Generate a mathematical sequence of real numbers in Maxima

Tags: maxima-software

I need to perform a function that calculates the $n$th term of the next succession:

$1, 6, 16, 37, 63, 113, 163, 248, 339, 469, 591, 801, 971, 1221$...

For more information about the succession, I leave you **[this link](https://oeis.org/A064602)**.

I have tried to do it with the following code:

```
succession(n) :=
 sum(divsum(k,2), k, 1, n)$
```

For small numbers, such as six or seven, it works. But, the problem is that they ask me to make the program able to compile the following cases:

`succession(10^17)`

`succession(12^24)`

I have already raised this question in stackOverflow, but many have recommended I post it here.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume that $O(n)$ would not be acceptable for you?

Comment: Honestly, I prefer a sublinear or logarithmic order function. But, I'm not going to get picky either, on top of that they help me.  @Levent

Comment: @Levent  Do you know it?